# Shrink does not work for free space in sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am trying to shrink database which has a simple recovery model.It has about 10 gb free space but it did not change.

Here is how i get free space and shrink comment

```
select
a.FILEID,name,
convert(decimal(12,2),round(a.size/128.000,2)) as FILE_SIZE_MB,
convert(decimal(12,2),round(fileproperty(a.name,'SpaceUsed')/128.000,2))as [SPACE_USED_MB],
convert(decimal(12,2),round((a.size-fileproperty(a.name,'SpaceUsed'))/128.000,2))[FREE_SPACE_MB] ,
NAME = left(a.NAME,15),
FILENAME = left(a.FILENAME,30)
from
dbo.sysfiles a
```

Here is the comment how i shrink file

```
dbcc shrinkfile(<file_name>,<space_used_mb>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually shrinkfile's 2nd argument is target_space, not 'space_used_mb'.
So, the following code should cut your data file, if the db is small enough.

```
USE master
GO
dbcc shrinkfile( fileId, 250 );
```

Also, you may consider using SHRINKDATABASE for you case (but be careful about that!)

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE ( [SHRINKED_DB_NAME] )
```

[Corresponding topic is here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11312/what-is-the-difference-between-shrink-database-and-file).